# Ubuntu 14.04 Install Fails

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, mount

So everytime i try to boot in ubuntu gnome 14 USB mounted image either PC reboots (after noveau errors) or when i get to installation (after mounting again tge iso file) it fails and reboots when installing grub on dev/sda4 leading to a non acessible linux.

Can anyone help me? I tried nomodeset, repair tool. But i simply can't pass trhough this install. I had ubuntu gnome installed previously but i formated the PC. Now i can't install it, as it fails everytime.

My laptop is

ASUS G551 JM
NVIDIA GEFORCE GTX 860 M

Hope i got you enough info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it! Thanks for your help cl-netbox. The USB ISO was probably corrupted so i built it using another iso (this was not at the first neither the second attempt).

When i finally got to Try withough intalling gnome (without editing the kernel to nouveau.modeset=0 and not leading to nouveau errors), i connected to internet and did on terminal:

```
sudo get-apt update
```

then I went to additional drivers and selected Nvidia recomended, rebooted and installed perfectly.